# Interrupt handler triggered when free_irq is called

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, irq

My problem is:
Interrupt handler get triggered when free_irq is called. I noticed in kernel messages that handler is invoked but since our device hasn't requested interrupt it prompted that no interrupt has received.
Is it expected behavior ? Can anybody please help ?

Comment: Interrupt handler will not be called unless the interrupt is captured for which your interrupt handler is registered. Can you give more details or can you share your code. So that our responses can be more productive.

Comment: You didn't specify that your driver is for a PCI device, but I've found useful documentation for the order of shutting down a device in PCI driver documentation. See: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/pci.html#pci-device-shutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are registering a handler for a (possibly) shared interrupt (with IRQF_SHARED), the interrupt can be triggered by other devices over which your driver has no control, so your driver must be prepared to receive an interrupt at any time.

To help with debugging drivers, the kernel will (when CONFIG_DEBUG_SHIRQ is set) fake some interrupts to check that your driver works correctly.
[[source code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/irq/manage.c?id=9073e1a804c3096eda84ee7cbf11d1f174236c75#n1281)]

Comment: I have shared interrupts but no other device has triggered interrupt as IRQ in /proc/interrupts is not incremented.
Secondly, can you please help how to check CONFIG_DEBUG_SHIRQ is set or not ?

Comment: The behaviour of your kernel proves that CONFIG_DEBUG_SHIRQ is set.

Comment: Is there a way to confirm this Macro ?

Comment: In my case I /proc/config.gz does not exist on Fedora 16.
I find config information ion /boot/config-<kernel> by running command
"cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep CONFIG_DEBUG_SHIRQ"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your post right - you must turn off issuing interrupts in your hardware *before* you call free_irq() then you won't receive interrupts while free_irq().